# Find function f(z) for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, banach-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Let $ f(z)= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } |z|<\frac{1}{2}\\
    0, &             \text{if} |z-2| <\frac{1}{2} \\
0, & \text{if} |z-3| <\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$

Let \begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -4 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & -6\\
2 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & -3\\
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Find  $f(A)$.

Attempt:

We know that $\mathbb{C}^6$ is a Hilbert space. and $B(\mathbb{C}^6) \simeq \mathbb{M_6}$. So we can consider $A$ as a function in $B(\mathbb{C}^6)$

And we can write $Ae_j= \sum_{n=1}^6a_n e_n$, where $(e_n)$ is the orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^6$.

Also I know that the spectrum $\sigma(A)= \{\text{eigenvalues of} A \}$

From here I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm trying to solve this using Banach Algebra point of view. But any other suggestions will be much appreciated too!

EDIT: My apologies, there was a typo in the original question. Now corrected

Thank you!

Comment: It may help to consult your definition of the functional calculus you use to define $f(A)$ in the first instance. Note that $A$ is not self-adjoint or normal and that $f$ is only partially defined on $\mathbb{C}$, and is not defined, for example, on a neighborhood of $0$, which I mention for example because it is in $\sigma(A)$ (note for example $(1,0,0,1,0,0)$ is in the null space of $A$). These facts are impediments to a lot of the usual functional calculi, and the calculation you would like to perform may need to detour from the usual approaches for this reason.

Comment: @leslietownes If you are interested, you can see how this evolved in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014659/find-exponent-of-a-matrix-that-is-isomorphic-to-b-mathbbcn/4014893#4014893

Comment: @JustDroppedIn cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important edit**: I just realized that $A$ is not a normal matrix. The technique below would work in general for a normal matrix, however I am not sure how $f(A)$ is even defined for a non-normal matrix. The continuous (or Borel for von Neumann algebras) functional calculus makes sense for normal elements only, as far as I remember.

Original Post:

Plugging the matrix in a calculator, you get the eigenvalues: $\sigma(A)=\{0,2,3\}$. The function $f$ you are defining is not defined on $0$, so I will write $c=f(0)$. If you can find a polynomial $p(z)$ such that $p(0)=c$, $p(2)=f(2)=0$ and $p(3)=f(3)=0$, (for example $p(z)=\frac{c}{6}(z-2)(z-3)$ is such a polynomial) then since $f=p$ on $\sigma(A)$ we have that $f(A)=p(A)$. But $p(A)$ is easily computed, for example if $p$ is the polynomial I mentioned earlier then
$$p(A)=\frac{c}{6}(A-2I)(A-3I).$$

Comment: I like this answer a lot, it goes a little more into the details that my comment only alluded to. At a high level, there are certainly ways of doing *something* to $A$ with that data, but they probably involve making additional assumptions and choices. And it isn't clear that all such choices will produce a result in a way that can really be regarded as "$f(A)$" in any useful sense (e.g., allowing for other computations with other "functions" of $A$ in a way that respects at least some aspects of function algebra).

Comment: @leslietownes Exactly! I just think that it is very useful thinking that, when applying the continuous functional calculus to an element with a finite spectrum, one can compute the elements $f(\cdot)$ by finding a polynomial that interpolates the values $f(x)$ where $x$ ranges in the spectrum. I thought of this today for the first time and it seems like a very useful result!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. My apologies that there was a typo, that why $f$ wasn't defined on $0$. But your answer is indeed very helpful.

Comment: @Rye glad i could help.

Comment: @Rye May I ask, are you leaving this unaccepted because you are expecting of a more informative answer? If there is something further you are looking for we can discuss about it.

Comment: I'm just wondering, as the matrix is not normal and now the question is corrected, would the above method still work? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Rye the problem is, how does one even define f(A) for a non-normal matrix? There is no standard definiton for such a thing.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: Just a quick question, does this involve the use of the spectral mapping theorem (the polynomial version)? Thanks!

Comment: @Rye Well, no but the continuous functional calculus is involved..